# Developing a Delphi console app for Raspberry Pi

Tags: delphi

I believe that it would be easier to use Lazarus, but I am familiar with Delphi, and am using XE8.

I want to develop a command line only app for Raspberry Pi which will use the UART and interface with external hardware by GPIO.

Can I do that with Delphi XE8? If so, which project type should I choose?

Comment: I don't think so. I think the earliest this is possible is Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: Hmmm, then it's Lazarus or an expensive upgrade. Tough choice

Comment: I can't be too sure, I've never used either, but if I'm not mistaken, Linux support was added in 10.2 Tokyo, and that's what you would need to target a Raspberry Pi (I'm assuming they're Linux based).

Comment: Raspberry PI is built on an ARM processor. No Delphi support. Look for [FreePascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_on_Raspberry_Pi).

Comment: Note Delphi on Linux does not support ARM processors. Some attempts to run Delphi and Android on Raspberry has been made though.

Comment: I had no real experience of Lazarus, only Delphi, until 3 months ago, but had no real difficulty writing a gui-based DB app that runs fine under Raspbian on the Rasberry Pi.  Lazarus and its debugger run fine on the R Pi, too, as long as it is a recent one.  Most of my testbeds for it were Linux console apps.

Comment: Why don't you use Python or a language that has good support on the pi? Branch out. You might benefit from learning another language.

Comment: See [Delphi on Raspberry Pi](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/delphi-on-raspberry-pi) and [Running Delphi applications on Raspberry Pi 3](http://fixedbycode.blogspot.com/2016/12/running-delphi-applications-on.html)

Answer (score 1):

Set android os on raspbery pi and use delphi xe8